# Ca not use PHPExcel objects as global object

Tags: php, phpexcel

I use PHPExcel objects like this:

```
class MyClass
{

  private $xlsFile, $xlsWorksheet;

  private function FunctionA()
  {
    $this->xlsFile = new PHPExcel();
    $this->xlsWorksheet = $this->xlsFile->getActiveSheet();

    $this->FunctionB();

    $writer = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($this->xlsFile);
    $writer->save('filename.xlsx');
  }

  private function FunctionB()
  {

    $this->xlsWorksheet->GetCellByColumnAndRow(1, 1)->setValue('Value');

  }

}
```

I get a file, but it is empty. No string 'value' on row-col 1,1.

But if I put the body of FunctionB inside FunctionA, I get the file with string 'value'.

I called FunctionA.

What would be the problem?

Comment: You can only call `FunctionB()` iff you call `FunctionA()` first, since `$this->xlsWorksheet` is set in `FunctionA()`.

Comment: josh, I called FunctionA.

Comment: The code snippet works for me as expected. Where are you calling `FunctionA`? In simplifying the problem to post here, I think you may have removed the issue.

Comment: @JacobBudin, you are right. By simplifying I removed the real problem. In the real FunctionB I call to a variable with a wrong name.